# what if int data type in mysql reaches limit while insert records?

Tags: mysql

Although using daily in my programming , but never realized about this question :

since the `int(unsigned)` data type can hold values from `0 to 4294967295`, what actually happens
If I declare this INT fields to be auto increment and one morning, it just reaches `4294967295`?
The obvious answer will be it should throw an error that cannot insert further, but data never stops comin and we have to store the records that still keep commin. What to do in this case?

Also is declaring int(20) will be large enough than this default limit?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: 20 doesn't change the datatype, it's just used for padding. Use a BIGINT for larger integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get 4 billion rows, the fact that the field will overflow is probably the least of your problems.

You can declare it to be BIGINT, which holds 8 bytes. Meaning that it will count up to 18446744073709551615.

If it overflows it will go back to 0, and keep inserting, returning an error if a row exists with that number.

Comment: I am interested to know the strategy for big databases where they have billions of records. I guess GUID or UUID would be a choice then?

Comment: Autoincremented bigint is the way to go if you just want to make sure. Filling up 18 quintillion rows is going to take some time, even with a computer doing all the work constantly. Not to mention the space it's going to consume. I don't think there has ever been an application that had that many records. Maybe a badly structured DNA database, but i seriously doubt they'd be that stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Use BIGINT - interval is 0 - 18446744073709551615